# My camera is being detected as a generic USB device, but not as a camera - how do I force /dev/videoX to be created?

Tags: usb-device, camera

EDIT: I added some additional information from `sudo lsusb` and `sudo dmesg` as recommended by telcoM below. I have one camera that works and a similar camera from the same manufacturer that doesn't work on Linux but does work on Windows.

When I plug my webcam into a USB port, it is not being detected as a camera.

here is the output of `lsusb` prior to plugging the camera in:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6720 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5842 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After plugging the device in:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 025: ID 32e4:8830  
Bus 002 Device 024: ID 2109:8110 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6720 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5842 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can see that a device has been added. Running `sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/025` gives:

```
Device: ID 32e4:8830  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x32e4 
  idProduct          0x8830 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 HD USB Camera
  iProduct                1 HD USB Camera
  iSerial                 3 2020040501
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x038d
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              256mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               5 HD USB Camera
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 HD USB Camera
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x006c
        dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             5
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                28
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 3
        guidExtensionCode         {28f03370-6311-4a2e-ba2c-6890eb334016}
        bNumControl            24
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            3
        bmControls( 0)       0xff
        bmControls( 1)       0xff
        bmControls( 2)       0xff
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                29
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {bd5321b4-d635-ca45-b203-4e0149b301bc}
        bNumControl            32
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            4
        bmControls( 0)       0x03
        bmControls( 1)       0x80
        bmControls( 2)       0x3f
        bmControls( 3)       0x9f
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x0000000e
          Auto-Exposure Mode
          Auto-Exposure Priority
          Exposure Time (Absolute)
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000177f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               6
        bMaxBurst               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bMaxBurst               0
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0f 24 01 02 df 02 82 00 05 02 01 01 01 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0b 24 06 01 0a 00 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 01 00 40 06 b0 04 00 40 77 1b 00 40 77 1b 4d 9a 3a 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 02 00 c0 0c 90 09 00 40 4d 72 00 40 4d 72 4d da f3 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 03 00 20 0a 98 07 00 d0 14 48 00 d0 14 48 4d c8 99 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 04 00 00 08 00 06 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 2d 4d 02 60 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 05 00 00 05 c0 03 00 00 94 11 00 00 94 11 4d 82 25 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 06 00 00 04 00 03 00 00 80 16 00 00 80 16 4d 02 18 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 07 00 20 03 58 02 00 a0 bb 0d 00 a0 bb 0d 4d a8 0e 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 08 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 ca 08 00 00 ca 08 4d 62 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 09 00 40 01 f0 00 00 80 32 02 00 80 32 02 4d 5a 02 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 0a 00 40 06 b0 04 00 40 77 1b 00 40 77 1b 4d 9a 3a 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  26 24 03 00 08 c0 0c 90 09 20 0a 98 07 00 08 00 06 40 06 b0 04 00 05 c0 03 00 04 00 03 20 03 58 02 80 02 e0 01 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1b 24 04 02 0a 59 55 59 32 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 10 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 01 00 40 06 b0 04 00 80 4f 12 00 80 4f 12 00 98 3a 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 02 00 c0 0c 90 09 00 80 3d 0f 00 80 3d 0f 00 d8 f3 00 40 4b 4c 00 01 40 4b 4c 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 03 00 20 0a 98 07 00 90 6a 0e 00 90 6a 0e 00 c6 99 00 d5 dc 32 00 01 d5 dc 32 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 04 00 00 08 00 06 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 60 00 d5 dc 32 00 01 d5 dc 32 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 05 00 00 05 c0 03 00 00 b8 0b 00 00 b8 0b 00 80 25 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 06 00 00 04 00 03 00 00 80 07 00 00 80 07 00 00 18 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 07 00 20 03 58 02 00 a0 bb 0d 00 a0 bb 0d 00 a6 0e 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 08 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 ca 08 00 00 ca 08 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 09 00 40 01 f0 00 00 80 32 02 00 80 32 02 00 58 02 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 0a 00 40 06 b0 04 00 80 4f 12 00 80 4f 12 00 98 3a 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  26 24 03 00 08 c0 0c 90 09 20 0a 98 07 00 08 00 06 40 06 b0 04 00 05 c0 03 00 04 00 03 20 03 58 02 80 02 e0 01 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  06 24 0d 01 01 04
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000c
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   2
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is High Speed (480Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         231 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

Running `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` shows only my integrated camera, not the USB camera that I just plugged in.

```
Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate (usb-0000:00:14.0-11):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

When I run `udevadm monitor` while plugging in the camera, I see the following:

```
KERNEL[6495.827968] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4 (usb)
KERNEL[6495.830203] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6495.831815] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6495.831900] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4 (usb)
UDEV  [6495.838037] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4 (usb)
UDEV  [6495.839827] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6495.841660] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6495.844529] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4 (usb)
KERNEL[6498.523402] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2 (usb)
KERNEL[6498.528879] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6498.534396] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/media1 (media)
KERNEL[6498.534515] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/input/input34 (input)
KERNEL[6498.534826] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/input/input34/event13 (input)
KERNEL[6498.534898] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6498.534955] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[6498.535019] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2 (usb)
UDEV  [6498.542294] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2 (usb)
UDEV  [6498.545007] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [6498.545291] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6498.546363] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/media1 (media)
UDEV  [6498.547609] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/input/input34 (input)
UDEV  [6498.617161] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/input/input34/event13 (input)
UDEV  [6498.621564] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6498.626172] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2 (usb)
```

Lots of action, but nothing related to a video4linux device.

Here is the relevant portion of `sudo dmesg`:

```
[93748.440857] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[93748.697861] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=8110, bcdDevice= 2.90
[93748.697873] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[93748.697877] usb 2-4: Product: USB3.0 Hub             
[93748.697880] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[93748.700414] hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found
[93748.700656] hub 2-4:1.0: 2 ports detected
[93751.387006] usb 2-4.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[93751.477156] usb 2-4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=32e4, idProduct=8830, bcdDevice= 1.00
[93751.477168] usb 2-4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[93751.477173] usb 2-4.2: Product: HD USB Camera
[93751.477176] usb 2-4.2: Manufacturer: HD USB Camera
[93751.477179] usb 2-4.2: SerialNumber: 2020040501
[93751.483406] usb 2-4.2: Found UVC 1.00 device HD USB Camera (32e4:8830)
[93751.488907] usb 2-4.2: No streaming interface found for terminal 5.
[93751.489209] input: HD USB Camera: HD USB Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.2/2-4.2:1.0/input/input41
```

In contrast, here are the same outputs when I plug in the camera that works. First `sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/014`

```
Device: ID 32e4:8830  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x32e4 
  idProduct          0x8830 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 HD USB Camera
  iProduct                1 HD USB Camera
  iSerial                 3 2020040498
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0381
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              256mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               5 HD USB Camera
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 HD USB Camera
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x006c
        dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             5
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                28
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 3
        guidExtensionCode         {28f03370-6311-4a2e-ba2c-6890eb334016}
        bNumControl            24
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            3
        bmControls( 0)       0xff
        bmControls( 1)       0xff
        bmControls( 2)       0xff
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                29
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {bd5321b4-d635-ca45-b203-4e0149b301bc}
        bNumControl            32
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            4
        bmControls( 0)       0x03
        bmControls( 1)       0x80
        bmControls( 2)       0x3f
        bmControls( 3)       0x9f
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x0000000e
          Auto-Exposure Mode
          Auto-Exposure Priority
          Exposure Time (Absolute)
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000177f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          White Balance Temperature
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0f 24 01 02 df 02 82 00 05 02 01 01 01 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  0b 24 06 01 0a 00 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 01 00 40 06 b0 04 00 40 77 1b 00 40 77 1b 4d 9a 3a 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 02 00 c0 0c 90 09 00 40 4d 72 00 40 4d 72 4d da f3 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 03 00 20 0a 98 07 00 d0 14 48 00 d0 14 48 4d c8 99 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 04 00 00 08 00 06 00 00 00 2d 00 00 00 2d 4d 02 60 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 05 00 00 05 c0 03 00 00 94 11 00 00 94 11 4d 82 25 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 06 00 00 04 00 03 00 00 80 16 00 00 80 16 4d 02 18 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 07 00 20 03 58 02 00 a0 bb 0d 00 a0 bb 0d 4d a8 0e 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 08 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 ca 08 00 00 ca 08 4d 62 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 09 00 40 01 f0 00 00 80 32 02 00 80 32 02 4d 5a 02 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 07 0a 00 40 06 b0 04 00 40 77 1b 00 40 77 1b 4d 9a 3a 00 2a 2c 0a 00 01 2a 2c 0a 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  26 24 03 00 08 c0 0c 90 09 20 0a 98 07 00 08 00 06 40 06 b0 04 00 05 c0 03 00 04 00 03 20 03 58 02 80 02 e0 01 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1b 24 04 02 0a 59 55 59 32 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 10 01 00 00 00 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 01 00 40 06 b0 04 00 80 4f 12 00 80 4f 12 00 98 3a 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 02 00 c0 0c 90 09 00 80 3d 0f 00 80 3d 0f 00 d8 f3 00 40 4b 4c 00 01 40 4b 4c 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 03 00 20 0a 98 07 00 90 6a 0e 00 90 6a 0e 00 c6 99 00 d5 dc 32 00 01 d5 dc 32 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 04 00 00 08 00 06 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 60 00 d5 dc 32 00 01 d5 dc 32 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 05 00 00 05 c0 03 00 00 b8 0b 00 00 b8 0b 00 80 25 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 06 00 00 04 00 03 00 00 80 07 00 00 80 07 00 00 18 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 07 00 20 03 58 02 00 a0 bb 0d 00 a0 bb 0d 00 a6 0e 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 08 00 80 02 e0 01 00 00 ca 08 00 00 ca 08 00 60 09 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 09 00 40 01 f0 00 00 80 32 02 00 80 32 02 00 58 02 00 15 16 05 00 01 15 16 05 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  1e 24 05 0a 00 40 06 b0 04 00 80 4f 12 00 80 4f 12 00 98 3a 00 40 42 0f 00 01 40 42 0f 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  26 24 03 00 08 c0 0c 90 09 20 0a 98 07 00 08 00 06 40 06 b0 04 00 05 c0 03 00 04 00 03 20 03 58 02 80 02 e0 01 00
        INTERFACE CLASS:  06 24 0d 01 01 04
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000c
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0002
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled
```

And `udevadm monitor` for the camera that works:

```
KERNEL[6682.722836] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3 (usb)
KERNEL[6682.724650] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6682.736729] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/video4linux/video2 (video4linux)
KERNEL[6682.736795] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/video4linux/video3 (video4linux)
KERNEL[6682.736898] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/media1 (media)
KERNEL[6682.737039] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input35 (input)
KERNEL[6682.737245] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input35/event13 (input)
KERNEL[6682.737326] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[6682.737401] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[6682.737487] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[6682.737556] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3 (usb)
UDEV  [6682.761644] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3 (usb)
UDEV  [6682.765782] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [6682.765844] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6682.768518] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/media1 (media)
UDEV  [6682.769022] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [6682.769206] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/video4linux/video3 (video4linux)
UDEV  [6682.769302] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/video4linux/video2 (video4linux)
UDEV  [6682.769715] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input35 (input)
UDEV  [6682.877079] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input35/event13 (input)
UDEV  [6682.880687] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6682.891060] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3 (usb)
```

Finally `sudo dmesg`:

```
[92330.404900] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[92330.578969] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=32e4, idProduct=8830, bcdDevice= 1.00
[92330.578980] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[92330.578985] usb 1-3: Product: HD USB Camera
[92330.578989] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HD USB Camera
[92330.578992] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 2020040498
[92330.583178] usb 1-3: Found UVC 1.00 device HD USB Camera (32e4:8830)
[92330.594432] input: HD USB Camera: HD USB Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input39
```

The major difference seems to be the `No streaming interface found for terminal 5` line in dmesg.

How to I manually create a v4l2 device for this USB camera?

I have read a number of posts about using udev to assign stable names to cameras, but all of these posts seem to assume that some video device is created in the first place. Any rules that I create with `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"` don't have any effect because udev is only seeing `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` events.

Any insight would be appreciated ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/015` output *does* look like the device attempts to be an [UVC-compatible video device](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/) - but there are some signs that its device descriptor may have an error or two.

The vendor ID part of the device ID `32e4:8830` seems to refer to "Ailipu Technology Co., Ltd" [according to this USB ID search engine](https://www.the-sz.com/products/usbid/index.php?v=0x32E4). It's apparently a Chinese manufacturer of USB cameras in Shenzhen, China. Their own brand of USB cameras is apparently named "ELP" according to quick Googling.

First, did you run that `lsusb` command as root? On the second line of output, it says:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

Second, one of the VideoControl Interface Descriptors listed by `lsusb` has caused this warning:

```
Warning: Descriptor too short
```

According to UVC specification version 1.5, the VideoControl Interface descriptor for a Processing Unit should be at least 13 bytes in size, not 11 as claimed by this descriptor.

Third, in the Interface Descriptor for the Video Streaming interface, the `bInterfaceProtocol` value is 0

And at the very end of the `lsusb` output, there is a bunch of data the command was unable to parse, and displayed as a hex dump instead. There might be some sort of error in the interface descriptor data that causes some of it to be garbled. That might result in problems trying to use the device.

Fourth, the device claims UVC specification version 1.00:

```
bcdUVC               1.00
```

The [version 1.50 of the UVC specification](https://www.spinelelectronics.com/pdf/UVC%201.5%20Class%20specification.pdf) was released back in year 2012, so if this information is correct, this device is either quite old or intentionally using an old version of the specification.

(The best source for the UVC specification would be usb.org, however currently the [UVC specification 1.5 document package](https://www.usb.org/document-library/video-class-v15-document-set) there seems to be 0 bytes in size.)

And all the places where the descriptors would have been able to include any plain-language text strings are specifying zeroes, indicating that no such strings have been included. It looks like the descriptors of this camera are written to be maximally generic and un-identifying.

One of the important pieces of information the Linux `uvcvideo` driver would need decoded from the interface descriptors of the camera is the actual video format of the data the camera is outputting. Without that information the data would be meaningless.

Please check the `sudo dmesg` output: if the `uvcvideo` driver outputs any error messages when trying to identify the camera, those messages would be found in there. The content of those messages might help in understanding the issue.

Comment: thanks for the thorough reply ... much appreciated. I added information from ```sudo lsusb``` and ```sudo dmesg```. The two cameras are very similar and both made by the same manufacturer. ELP makes the camera body using a Sony IMX179 sensor.

Comment: Hmm... very similar indeed. In fact, their product IDs are the same and serial numbers are just 3 units apart. But the failing camera claims USB 3 SuperSpeed support, while the working one claims just USB 2 High Speed. Does the failing camera actually have the extra row of 5 contacts deep in the "throat" of the USB plug? (And if it does, do they actually work, I wonder?) If not, this might be fake USB3 support: the "USB3" version of the camera claims USB3 support but actually just falls back to USB2 in Windows, while Linux takes it for its word, attempts to use USB3 and fails.

Comment: If you happen to have a USB2-only Linux system at hand, try plugging the failing camera to it. Or try connecting the camera with a short USB2-only extension cable in between the computer and the camera to try and force fallback to USB2. If either of those make the camera work with Linux, then the USB3 SuperSpeed implementation of the camera would seem to be either faulty or an outright fake.

Comment: so it turns out that I missed an important difference. Both of the cameras are hard mounted some distance away from my computer and they have extension cables. The camera that works is connected through a passive USB 2.0 extension cable. The camera that is failing is connected through an active USB 3.0 extension cable, so the cable has a powered hub in the cable. I should have gone to physically look at the cabling at the outset I guess. I don't think I can get a passive USB 2.0 cable that is long enough, so I am now trying to figure out how to make this setup work.